# AngularJS: reuse component with different parent

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have A and B reusable components. I want B to invoke a method on A - of course only if B is a child of A. Also - I want B to be used as a standalone component (without A as a parent). In such case the method from non-existing A shouldn't be invoked. My first try was to get controller in link function (exactly in the same way as if I had `require: "^A"` specified on B - now I cannot have it because I want to use B also as a standalone component) - but this doesn't work:

```
var module = angular.module("mymodule", []);

// <A>
module.directive("A", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            this.register = function() {
               console.log("Hooray!");
            };
        },
        template:
            '<div class="ng-a" ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});

// <B>
module.directive("B", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, refA) {
            if (refA !== undefined) {
                refA.register();
            } else {
                console.log("Standalone");
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // Do something.
        },
        template:
            '<div class="ng-b" ng-transclude></div>'
    };
});
```

For use case:

```
<A><B></B></A><B></B>
```

console output should be:

```
Hooray!
Standalone
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can conditionally require another directive prefixing it with the question mark: `require: "^?A"`. Then you can test for the controller being not-null to see if you were invoked inside a parent directive or as a standalone.

Comment: is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I'll just leave this here for anyone looking for documentation on [require prefixes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-), like I was.