# Angular.js: watch one object's height and update other object's padding

Tags: events, resize, angularjs

I can watch in a directive one object's property (actually - clientHeight). But how to change other object's padding-top according to this height? I know how to do this using jQuery, but I am looking for an Angular way.

In Angular one can access some page element using a directive. Ok, but how to access other page element in the same directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  For all of the suggestions below, assume you have two directives – one for watching the clientHeight, the other for adjusting the padding.

- Create a service (that is injected into both directives).  Have the first directive modify an object property in the service (e.g., `someObj.prop1`).  The other directive $watches that object property.
- Use events.  Have the first directive $emit or $broadcast an event and the second directive can listen for it using $on (in its link function or in its own controller).
- If there is an ancestor relationship, you can `require` the ancestor directive's controller in the descendant directive. See [AngularJS: reuse component with different parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538839/angularjs-reuse-component-with-different-parent) for an example.
- Not recommended, but another option: use $rootScope instead of a service: inject $rootScope into both directives.  Have the first directive modify an object property on $rootScope.  The other directive $watches that object property.

Comment: +1. Which method would you prefer if you were to do this in your application and why?

Comment: @Trevor, if the two elements on which the directives are used are related and always/naturally have an ancestor-descendant relationship, I'd go with `require`.  If there may be (now or in the future) some additional information sharing going on between these directives, a service.  If this is a one-off get-it-done-quick app, or I'm feeling lazy, $rootScope or events.