# What does ? mean in a directive's require property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Some directives use some cryptic chars in their require property, like the [angular ui dropdow](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.js#L117)

```
require:"?^dropdown"
```

I'm ok with `^` which mean parent but I can't figured out what `?` means.

Thank you!

Comment: I think this answer covers it http://stackoverflow.com/a/14539052/542251

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for the link. I'm quite new to SO and I'm not sure to understand your previous comment. Could you explain it more clearly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: reuse component with different parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538839/angularjs-reuse-component-with-different-parent)

Comment: Ok so I correct my mistakes. thx. About duplicate question, I think the question as I ask it is clearer so I hope, easier to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code says:

```
[
    'siblingDirectiveName', 
    '^parentDirectiveName', 
    '?optionalSiblingDirectiveName', 
    '?^optionalParentDirectiveName'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

check the docs: [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) 'require'

the directive docs have been moved there a while ago

have a nice weekend!